# My functions not identifying as defined (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I added routers to my project and kept working and I don't know exactly what I did that caused the terminal to stop identifying the functions as defined... But probably that's because of the syntax or the location but I can't locate the exact problems.. I would love some help.. Thanks! (:

[Print Screen of the Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HYLa.png)

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Addroom from './components/Addroom.js';
import Boxroom from './components/Boxroom.js';
import Room from './components/Room.js';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

state = {
  roomsList: [],
  isActive: false,
  myFilledRoom: []
};

handleShow = () => {
  this.setState({ isActive: true });
};

handleHide = () => {
  this.setState({ isActive: false });
};

create = r => {
  this.setState({
    roomsList: [...this.state.roomsList, r],
    isActive: false
  });
};

FilledRoom = () => {

  this.setState({
   Room:[...this.state.myFilledRoom]
  })
};

function App() { 
 return (
   <div className="backGroundMain" style={{backgroundColor: "lightseagreen", height: "600px", width: "850px"}}>
        <h1 style={{backgroundColor: "aquamarine", height: "40px", width: "270px", borderRadius: "5px", border: "2px", margin: "15px"}} >My Smart House</h1>

<h1>My Smart House</h1>

<Router>

 <div className="row">

   <div className="col-6"><Link to='/Boxroom'>My Rooms</Link></div>
   <div className="col-6"><Link to='/'>Homepage</Link></div>

   </div>

<Switch>


<Route exact path='/' component={()=>{return <App/>}}/>
<Route exact path='/Boxroom' component={()=>{return <Boxroom FilledRoom={Room}/>}}/>

        {this.state.roomsList.map((element, key) => {
          return (
            <Room
              id={key + 1}
              key={key}
              r={element.room}
              rt={element.roomType}
              ct={element.colorType}
              sr={element.boxColor}
            />
          );
        })}

        {this.state.isActive ? (
          <Addroom add={this.create} />
        ) : (
          <button style={{backgroundColor: "aquamarine", height: "20px", width: "60px", borderRadius: "5px", border: "2px"}} onClick={this.handleShow}>Create</button>
        )}
      </div>


</Switch>

</Router>
    

    </div>
 )
 }
export default App;
```

Comment: Please post text, not links to images of text.

Comment: Your functions aren’t part of the component, thus not a property of “this”, nor do the functions have a meaningful “this” inside them.

Comment: And functional components don’t have state unless you’re using hooks, and then it’s not called “state” unless you explicitly call it that, and again, there’s no “this” involved. There’s a lot going wrong here.

Comment: Unrelated, but if you have css classes then why also use a wad of inline styles?

Comment: You use IDE? It's full of errors when you dont define var, const or let keywords to define variable or function!! It clearly says that you haven't defined it. It comes down to basics of JS. Please check.